# How do I make this expand/collapse FAQ list to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, accordion

Here's my list that I want to expand/collapse: My goal is simply to toggle expand/collapse, to have this list act like an accordion. What I don't understand is how to get the <div> from a hidden state to a visible state using the javascript provided below. Any resources or direct help is greatly appreciated.

#### Shipping

```
<li class="plusimageapply"><a name="faq-question">Why do I see prices for some items and not others? How do I get pricing on items that I want to buy?</a></li>

<div style="display: none;">Ths is a sampel of an answer tot he above question.</div>

<li class="plusimageapply"><a name="faq-question">How do I handle an overnight delivery?</a></li>

<div style="display: none;">AMOeasy offers five overnight shipping options. During checkout, simply check the option that best meets your needs and process your order.
  <ul>
    <li>UPS orders must be placed before 5:30pm EST / 2:30pm PST.</li>
    <li>FedEx orders must be place before 8:00pm EST / 5:00pm PST.</li>
  </ul>
  If you are concerned that the item may not be in stock, please call customer service at 877-AMO-4LIFE (877-266-4543).
</div>
```

The following is the JavaScript I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').click(function () {
        var questionname= this.name;
        $("#"+questionname).toggle();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("minusimageapply");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any elements with an `id` in your code, whereas the `$("#"+questionname)` selects an element whose `id` is equal to whatever is returned by `questionname`. Also, a `div` is not a valid child of a `ul` or `ol`, and an `li` is an invalid child of anything *except* an `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm quite a novice, as it can be seen, in understanding JavaScript and how it relates and change HTML&CSS. I'm much clearer on the relationship between `ol`, `ul` and `li` vs `div` Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest some valid HTML (given that an `li` is a valid child of ***only*** an `ol` or `ul` and a `div` is ***not*** a valid child of ***either*** of those elements), such as:

```
<ul>
    <li class="q">Question One</li>
    <li>first answer to question one</li>
    <li>second answer to question one</li>
    <li class="q">Question two</li>
    <li>first answer to question two</li>
    <li>second answer to question two</li>
    <li class="q">Question three</li>
    <li>first answer to question three</li>
    <li>second answer to question three</li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('li:not(".q")').hide();

$('li.q').click(
    function(){
        $('li:not(".q")').slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wkat3/).

Or with a `dl`:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Question One</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question one</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question one</dd>
    <dt>Question two</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question two</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question two</dd>
    <dt>Question three</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question three</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question three</dd>
</dl>
​
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('dd').hide();

$('dt').click(
    function() {
        var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('dt');
        toggle.slideToggle();
        $('dd').not(toggle).slideUp();
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wkat3/1/).

Comment: A big THANK YOU to you sir. Especially for the link to jsfiddle.net. I didn't know such a service existed. The examples you gave will help me on my next task. For this task I needed to hand it off to another developer to expedite it. Your help and examples are greatly appreciated. Take care!

Comment: May I suggest then, that if these answers were useful to you, that you up-vote them (clicking on the ▲ besides the answer) or accept the answer (click on the ✓ besides the answer that *most* helped, since you can accept only one answer per question). See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I want to but I'm ultra-new to stackoverflow and don't even have the minimum 15 reputation points. However, I was able to check this answer. Thank you again David.

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
$('li a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().next().toggleClass("minusimageapply").slideToggle();
});​
```

[**Live example **](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3HaT/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I wasn't able to make it work with what I was trying to do. Mostly thank you for the live example. I didn't know such a service existed to play with JavaScript, Styling, and HTML. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Or this...

```js
$('li.faq-answer').hide();
$('li.faq-question').click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li {
        list-style:none;
}
li.faq-question {
 font-weight: 700;
}
li.faq-question:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="faq-question">Question 1</li>
 <li class="faq-answer">Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.</li>
 <li class="faq-question">Question 2</li>
 <li class="faq-answer">Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</li>
 <li class="faq-question">Question 3</li>
 <li class="faq-answer">Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</li>
 <li class="faq-question">Question 4</li>
 <li class="faq-answer">Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</li>
 <li class="faq-question">Question 5</li>
 <li class="faq-answer">Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
</ul>
```