# Expand/collapse FAQ with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've been searching expand/collapse menu script (becouse i can do only "expand" without colapse so far) and found one that interests me. Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077683/how-do-i-make-this-expand-collapse-faq-list-to-work)

Still, when i used it with jQuery i've seen only text [so far](http://scr.hu/0z5b/iajxi
)

When i used other script, it worked (but it still does not include collapsing in FAQ).

Can any one help me me?

Ofc script

`<dl>
        <dt>Question One</dt>
        <dd>first answer to question one</dd>
        <dd>second answer to question one</dd>
        <dt>Question two</dt>
        <dd>first answer to question two</dd>
        <dd>second answer to question two</dd>
        <dt>Question three</dt>
        <dd>first answer to question three</dd>
        <dd>second answer to question three</dd>
    </dl>`

And so far jquery:

```
<script>
$('dd').hide();$('dt').click(
function() {
    var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('dt');
    toggle.slideToggle();
    $('dd').not(toggle).slideUp();
});​
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem? working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/4pC3e/12/

Comment: Would like say same, but i can just see text http://scr.hu/0z5b/iajxi can't click on text or even if i do - nothing happens. Like, i know this code works on jsfiddle, but not on my page. Don't know why.

Comment: @user3770730, by using JqueryUI you can use accordian as documented here http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ .Is is so simple and nice to use.

Comment: @user3770730 put that in document.ready http://jsfiddle.net/4pC3e/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this site . Same functionality can be achived using jqueryUI accordion.

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Edited file

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
            <title>Title</title>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $("document").ready(function()
            {
            $('dd').hide();
            $('dt').click(function()
            {
            var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('dt');
            toggle.slideToggle();
            $('dd').not(toggle).slideUp();
            });
            });
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <dl>
            <dt>Question One</dt>
            <dd>first answer to question one</dd>
            <dd>second answer to question one</dd>
            <dt>Question two</dt> 
            <dd>first answer to question two</dd>
            <dd>second answer to question two</dd>
            <dt>Question three</dt>
            <dd>first answer to question three</dd>
            <dd>second answer to question three</dd>
            </dl>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

here is the code which works

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('dd').hide();
$('dt').click(function() {
var toggle = $(this).nextUntil('dt');
toggle.slideToggle();
$('dd').not(toggle).slideUp();
});
});
</script>
<dl>
    <dt>Question One</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question one</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question one</dd>
    <dt>Question two</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question two</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question two</dd>
    <dt>Question three</dt>
    <dd>first answer to question three</dd>
    <dd>second answer to question three</dd>
</dl>
```

nothing to do special, if not work update your browser as well.

Comment: Hi guys,
Thanks all of you for reply; thanks for accordion page (i'll really study from them), but most of thanks Zahid for this script. Yeah, it worked, but i must confess that i'm just stupid.
My browser just blocked some of javascripts, so some worked-some didnt.
Just cleaned cookies and stuff then it worked all again.

Thanks once again, you guys were faster than Bolt. :)